# MS Access query in PHP returns no results

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, pdo, odbc

I have a query in MS Access that is saved and works when launched directly from ms access.

I created a php page that outputs that information by calling this query by name, but query does not return anything!
My code should work since there are other queries in Access which I call, and they do return data.

- Query works when launched(double-clicked) in Access
- Query does not return results when typed and executed from PHP `"SELECT * see query below"`
- Query does not return results when called by MS Access-name from PHP `"SELECT * FROM Query1"`
- Other queries in the same database executed as expected when called by MS Access-name from PHP `"SELECT * FROM Query2"`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT a2.[vendor_oel_yr], 
               Count(a2.qty) AS eol_qty 
        FROM   (SELECT "wintel"                               AS Platform, 
                       s.city & "," & s.state                AS 
                       [Physical Location], 
                       ""                                     AS 
                       [Special Flag (Project)], 
                       ""                                     AS 
                       [Special Flag (sub location)], 
                       ""                                     AS 
                       [location Floor], 
                       ""                                     AS 
                       [Room Discriptor], 
                       Format(s.unitprce, "currency")         AS [Unit Price], 
                       "hp"                                   AS Manufacturer, 
                       t.make_model                           AS Model, 
                       s.itemnmbr                             AS [Part Number], 
                       s.qty                                  AS Qty, 
                       s.itemdesc                             AS Description, 
                       s.sn                                   AS [Serial Number] 
                       , 
                       "" 
                       AS [Asset Tag #], 
                       ""                                     AS Environment, 
                       t.computer                             AS 
                               [Device Name (Naming Standard)], 
                       s.docdate                              AS [Install Date], 
                       4                                      AS 
                       [Vendor Useful Life], 
                       ""                                     AS 
                       [Operational Useful Life], 
                       s.docdate + ( 4 * 365 )                AS 
                       [Vendor EOL Date], 
                       ""                                     AS 
                       [Operational EOL Date] 
                       , 
                       Format(s.qty * s.unitprce, "currency") AS 
                       [Purchase Price], 
                       Year(s.docdate + ( 4 * 365 ))          AS Vendor_OEL_Yr 
                FROM   sayers_invoice AS s 
                       INNER JOIN tamit_wintel AS t 
                               ON s.sn = t.serial_number 
                WHERE  Len(s.sn) > 0) AS a2 
        GROUP  BY a2.[vendor_oel_yr]) AS a2O;
```

Comment: done any debugging? checked return values on the db calls in php?

Comment: I have multiple calls for multiple queries(same database). They all work from PHP. The only exception this query - and it works when called from MS Access

Comment: Have you tried executing the result query directly on access?

Comment: just because other queries work means nothing. CHECK THE RETURN VALUES. if you get back a failure indication, whatever DB library you're using SHOULD have some method of telling you what the error was.

Comment: I am stuck here and not sure what to do. I tried typing this query in PHP and calling it - PDO returns empty result set. Is there any way to debug it?

Comment: Added more info above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like complex query made this problem.
I had to optimize the query and then it worked.